# Kali Linux - PPS State Mismatch

Tags: xorg, nvidia-graphics-card, kali-linux, optimus, xorg.conf

long time!

Recently, I updated my Kali rolling system and had my own working NVidia Optimus setup, and I was able to use my GeForce card on my HashCat.

Now, I lost my GUI.

I went through several articles online to reinstall, including:

http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/installing-nvidia-on-kali-2.0/

https://docs.kali.org/general-use/install-nvidia-drivers-on-kali-linux

https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?35748-TUTORIAL-Installing-official-NVIDIA-driver-in-Optimus-laptop

Every time I purge my NVidia drivers, I follow these steps, and ensure my Xorg.conf file maps to the correct Bus ID for my card, only to get “PPS Stare Mismatch” when I try the startx command.

I’ve also noticed when I’ve tried installing sometimes I’ll see “forcing reinstallation since link group glx is broken.”

I notice nothing in the Xorg.0.log that could tell me anything about what might be happening. No error messages.

Can anyone advise me on anything else to try?

Please see my current Xorg.conf file below:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 384.98  (buildd@debian)  Thu Nov 30 05:15:46 UTC 2017

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID      "PCI:4:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "intel"
    Driver     "modesetting"
    BusID      "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Kali in NOT intended for daily usage as a desktop distro. Surely it can be installed and also with Nvidia drivers but that is the exception, not the rule. Considering its intended usage installing proprietary drivers is nonsense unless absolutely required in those cases when the open source graphics driver has no support for, let's say, a bleeding edge chipset.

Comment: Yes, but I want to use Hashcat with my graphics card among many other things. And I KNOW it's possible to run X server off of my graphics card - I want to know I can play YouTube videos so I can run tutorials while I do my work.

Comment: Like any other rolling distro, expect things to break, anytime, without warning and without solution is sight. There are Kali forums that may provide some help from experienced users. Posting anywhere else is probably a waste of time. Good bye and good luck.